# cordova.plugins.locationManager.enableBluetooth() Not working in android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, bluetooth, ionic-framework

I am trying to enable my phone bluetooth via ionic app. I am calling something like this:

**`cordova.plugins.locationManager.enableBluetooth()`**

But not enabling and making any error also. Following is my **`app.js`** code. Please help out.

```
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';


@App({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
export class MyApp {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[Platform]];
  }

  constructor(platform) {
    this.rootPage = TabsPage;

    platform.ready().then(() => {
        StatusBar.backgroundColorByName('red');
        console.log("App starting.");
        cordova.plugins.locationManager.enableBluetooth();
    });
  }
}
```

Is there anything I am missing. My phone is One Plus One.

**UPDATE:**

> Is there any particular configuration I have to in device to achieve
>   this in develop mode

---

> **App technical info**
>
> - Ionic 2 & Angular 2
> - Plugin : com.unarin.cordova.beacon ([Link](https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon.git))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this myself. Seems to be issue was  with `petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon`, I was using 25days older plugin.

First removed the existing plugin by running by going into project root folder:

**`sudo cordova plugin rm com.unarin.cordova.beacon`**

Then again added the plugin (basically I updated my plugin):

**`sudo cordova plugin add https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon.git`**

After that everything started working fine.

Thanks.